# how to check if session is still exists in case browser was closed

Tags: node.js, angular, express-session, session-storage

Here is my scenario: After login to the app, on the next browser window opening - the user is already authenticated (using express-session) and it go straight to the content pages (without going through the login page). This behavior continues on the opening of the coming next browsers windows.
Now - the problem - I need to identify whenever the last browser window is closed - so I can clear the session.
I'm looking for some way to check whether the user closed the last (authenticated) browser window.
I assume this can be achieved by session storage, but couldn't figure out how to investigate it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the local-storage maintain the value event when the browser is closed and a new one is opened

Answer (score 1):

You should use [angular auth guard](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3), the standard way to maintain the authentication at the client-side.

Happy coding ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `canActivate` in routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashboard', 
    loadChildren: './master/master.module#MasterModule',
    canActivate: [AppRouteGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

and create a **AppRouteGuard Service** like this:

```
export class AppRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        if (localStorage.getItem('loginData') != null ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'])
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below. I am not 100% sure that it will satisfy all cases, there might be some edge cases that may need to be taken care separately.

1. Generate a tabId on server side, store it and send it as a header to browser tab.
2. Tab will read this (in JS) and assign it to a local variable
3. Tab should send it to server along with each request
4. When tab is closed, call the server to inform the tabId is closed
5. If tabId is not found in the request, server should set a new tabId
6. When last tabId for a given session is closed, logout the session on server

Comment: I've already implemented all above using a counter. The main and only problem is section 4: there is no way to identify that the tab is closed - event window:unload is triggered event when refreshing the page.

Comment: Ok....So consider a page refresh as new tab may be... Close the old tabId and create new one and send it to browser ?